# Problem getting tr tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

i'm new here and in python
i'm trying to get a number in td tag with BeautifulSoup but every time i failed

```html
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>خرید</td>
         <td>معامله</td>
         <td>فروش</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td id="dbp" class="">**18,390**</td>
         <td id="d02" class="">18,390&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:11px;color:green">870&nbsp;&nbsp;(4.97%)</span></td>
         <td id="dsp" class="">18,390</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>اولین</td>
         <td>پایانی</td>
         <td>دیروز</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td id="d04" class="">18,390</td>
         <td id="d03" class="">
            <span style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold">18,390</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:11px;color:green">870&nbsp;&nbsp;(4.97%)</span>
         </td>
         <td id="d05" class="">17,520</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

i need just 18,390 number in output which is in dbp id tag

Comment: can you provide the python code and the traceback?

Comment: @PanagiotisSimakis i tried many code but it didn't succeeded,every time i tried i got none or error

Comment: Please show us at least on of the full solutions you've tried, we can't identify your problem without seeing any code. Even if you code is not working, show us

Comment: ```url = ('http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=46348559193224090')
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
p = soup.find_all('td' , {'id' : 'dbp'})
print(p)```

Comment: and in output only i got []..nothing else

Comment: @P-_-JJ: Because it's a JS rendered page. If you check the page source you can't find them. You have to go for selenium then.

Comment: Ok..i'll try tnx

Comment: @P-_-JJ: I have edited my answer. Check that.

Comment: @Pygirl thank you very much...you solved my problem,just a little problem was there which i solved by import time,beside that every things work prefect...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
text = soup.find('td', {"id" : "dsp"}).text
```

---

**text:**

```
'18,390'
```

---

**Edit:**

This one is a js rendered page. So normal beautifulsoup method won't work. You need to wait for atleast few seconds so that all the scripts are executed. Using `Selenium` is one of the method.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time 
# import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=46348559193224090'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10) # <--- waits for 10 seconds so that page can gets rendered
# action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
# print(driver.page_source) # <--- this will give you source code 
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
rows = soup.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    shares = row.find('td', id='dsp')
    if shares:
        print(shares.text.strip())
        break
```

---

```
19,300
```

Comment: it didn't help.

Comment: How it didn't help? can you provide traceback?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):`
  `File "C:/Users/PJ/PycharmProjects/Test/1.py", line 10, in <module>`
   ` soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")`
 ` File "C:\Users\PJ\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 307, in __init__`
   ` elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()`

Comment: `html` is the text you have posted in your question. I copied your html source code as a string and assigned it to the` htm`l variable.

Comment: If it helped then mark it as an answer. If not, let me know.